# cast in for-loop and cast after doesn't return the same value

Tags: c, for-loop

I just tried to create a floor function by myself, it seems to work but I've got some problems with the for loop. I found that a cast always return the floor of a number, but sometimes it seems to be more tricky. This is the code :

```
for (double i = 0; i < 2.0; i+=0.1) {
    printf("i = %f, floor(i) = %d\n", i, (int)i);
}

printf("(int)1.0 = %d\n", (int)1.0);
```

When building and launching this code, for `i = 1.0`, `(int)i` return `0`, but in `printf`, *(int)1.0 = 1*. So, I'm a little bit confused.

Someone could help me to understand why ?

Comment: 0.1 + 0.1 + ... + 0.1 isn't exactly 1.0, floating point issue.

Comment: research floating point arithmetic

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the issue due to the loss of precision with floating numbers as 0.1+0.1+... is noy equal to 1.0. You can check [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

0.1 looks like this in double-precision. If you write this is binary, truncated to 57 significant bits:

```
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001…
```

Bits 54 and beyond total to greater than half the value of bit position 53, so this rounds up to

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

In decimal, this is

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

which is slightly greater than 0.1 and hence the unexpected result.

Comment: Bounties +1 for explanation